# no lan port detected

Tags: release-hera, wifi, networking

I want to install Elementary Hera on a new build using a 3700x, 1660ti, and a gigabyte b550i motherboard. On my first attempt, the install went completely fine. But I had no wireless or wired internet connection. Any thoughts on how to correct this? Do I need to manually install Realtek ethernet drivers?
Thanks

Comment: Which Realtek ethernet adapter do you have?

Comment: Realtek 2.5GbE LAN chip.  
Turns out all that I needed to do was install the latest Elementry iso. Originally, I used an older iso that I had on a thumbdrive.

Comment: If possible, please add your solution as an answer and mark as resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realtek 2.5GbE LAN chip. Turns out all that I needed to do was install the latest Elementry iso. Originally, I used an older iso that I had on a thumbdrive.